# PHP удаление тегов кроме тех, которые находятся внутри <code></code>

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, теги

Уважаемые специалисты, помогите разобраться, пример упрощенный. Допустим есть строка

```
$txt="вне тега<p>внутри</p><code><b>жирный</b></code><a href='#'>Ссылка</a>";
```

Необходимо удалить все теги кроме содержимого в `<code>`
чтобы получилось во так:

```
$txt="вне тега внутри <b>жирный</b> Ссылка";
```

Пример упрощенный теги могут быть любые, пока получилось удалить абсолютно все теги вот так:

```
$txt=preg_replace("~(\<(/?[^\>]+)\>)~uis"," ",$txt); 
echo($txt); //текст без тегов содержимое тега параграфа жирный шрифт Ссылка
```

Как добавить исключения для содержимого `<code>`? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: А почему просто не использовать strip_tags($txt,'<code>,<b>') ?

Comment: @Arsen потому что надо оставить вообще все тэги которые внутри `code`

Comment: @teran -  если тег <b> не постоянный, то тут конечно strip_tags не поможет )),  Игорь "теги могут быть любые" это в <code>могуть быть любые ?

Comment: @teran Арсен хороший дал совет, например функция `$txt=strip_tags($txt,'<code>');`  оставит и все что внутри code, но текст получится без пробелов так: `текст без теговсодержимое тега параграфа<code><b>жирный</b></code> шрифтСсылка` хотелось бы с пробелами.

Comment: хм. серьезно, strip оставляеть все что внутри?  я даже проверять что-то это не стал :D

Comment: @teran а не прошу прощения ошибся не оставляет

Comment: да я тоже проверил, не оставляет.

Comment: @Arsen любые и в code и вне

Comment: если начальные и конечные пробелы не важны, то можно просто заменить `<code>` на `<code> ` с пробелом. аналогично для закрываюшего, а потом сдлеать `trim` результату

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Один из вариантов :

```
$str = 'вне <br>тега<hr /><p><b>внутри</b></p><code><b>жирный</b> <b>жирный</b></code><a href="#">Ссылка</a>';

echo parse_string($str);


function parse_string($str, $need = 'code') {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '~<([a-z]+\d?)[^>]*>(.+?)</\1>~',
        function($m)use($need){
            return (strtolower($m[1]) != $need ? strip_tags($m[0]) : $m[2]);
        },
        preg_replace(['~<[a-z]{2,3}\s*/?>~', '~\s{2,}~'], ' ', $str) 
    );
}
```

Comment: дак `<p><b>внутри</b></p>` то оставит внутренние тэги

Comment: + еще проблема непарных тэгов

Comment: @teran ок, не парные теги не проблема, а о вложенных сейчас подумаю, спс :)

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо за помощь, я забыл уточнить тега `<code>` может и не быть в строке, к тому же у него может быть любая позиция (вначале, в середине или в конце). Например если в примере заменить тег code на font (или любой другой) вот так: `$txt="текст без тегов<p>содержимое тега параграфа</p><font><b>жирный шрифт</b></font><a href='www.link.ru'>Ссылка</a>";` то Ваше решение оставит все и внутри font.

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов подправил ответ, вроде бы всё учтено, пробуйте.

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо взял на заметку

Answer (score 2):

для вашего упрощенного примера можно строку разделить по `</?code>` после чего у нечетных частей удалить тэги, а у четных оставить как было. Решение может быть вот такое, но надо еще расставить пробелы.

```
$txt = "вне тега<p>внутри</p><code><b>жирный</b></code><a href='#'>Ссылка</a>";

$data = preg_split("/(<\/?code>)/", $txt);

$result = "";
foreach($data as $k => $str){
    $result .= ($k % 2) ?  $str : strip_tags($str);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: спасибо, просто мне казалось можно что-то вроде `$txt=preg_replace("~(^<code>)(\<(/?[^\>]+)\>)(^</code>)~uis"," ",$txt);`

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов это вариант решения, но не единственный.